# Page created using Curl script. Not showing up on Confluence page. Need suggestions

Tags: python, json, api, curl, confluence

I am stuck at creating a confluence page using following curl script.

```
curl -v -S -u user:pass -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"type":"page","title":"TestPage","space":{"key":"Cloud"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"<p>This is a new page</p>","representation":"storage"}}}' https://Client.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CD/Applications | python -mjson.tool
```

The script is executing fine and showing success result. But, the page is not displayed on Confluence Wiki page.

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  110k    0  110k  100   149   102k    138  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  102k
No JSON object could be decoded
```

Any Idea what I am missing in this config ??. Please help.

Comment: Should there be a space between -d and json values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you haven't used a correct URL for creating page via REST API. It has to be `URL/rest/api/content/` . For example, if you want to create a page with the title `new page` in the space with `space key TST` and the body `This is a new page`, you need to use following:

```
curl -u admin:admin -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"type":"page","title":"new page","space":{"key":"TST"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"<p>This is a new page</p>","representation":"storage"}}}' http://<URL>:<port>/confluence/rest/api/content/ | python -mjson.tool
```